# Data showing in different order with console.log / console.table

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, console.log

--I'm doing this exercise with sort() and when I'm logging it in a console.table, it shows in the correct order and when I log it with console.log it shows in the wrong order.

--If I log a single item, arr[0] for example, it's the correct one that should display.

--How do I get around this behavior , I don't want to keep using console.table moving forward and I want to see correct data....

[Console table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsr3z.png) <- printscreen with console table

[Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmkBE.png) <- printscreen with console log and console log [0]

```
const inventors = [
  { first: 'Albert', last: 'Einstein', year: 1879, passed: 1955 },
  { first: 'Isaac', last: 'Newton', year: 1643, passed: 1727 },
  { first: 'Galileo', last: 'Galilei', year: 1564, passed: 1642 },
  { first: 'Marie', last: 'Curie', year: 1867, passed: 1934 },
  { first: 'Johannes', last: 'Kepler', year: 1571, passed: 1630 },
  { first: 'Nicolaus', last: 'Copernicus', year: 1473, passed: 1543 },
  { first: 'Max', last: 'Planck', year: 1858, passed: 1947 },
  { first: 'Katherine', last: 'Blodgett', year: 1898, passed: 1979 },
  { first: 'Ada', last: 'Lovelace', year: 1815, passed: 1852 },
  { first: 'Sarah E.', last: 'Goode', year: 1855, passed: 1905 },
  { first: 'Lise', last: 'Meitner', year: 1878, passed: 1968 },
  { first: 'Hanna', last: 'Hammarström', year: 1829, passed: 1909 }
];

const outputThree = inventors.sort((a , b) => a.year - b.year )
console.table(outputThree)
console.log(outputThree)
console.log(outputThree[0])
```

Comment: Are you logging sorted array in `console.log`?

Comment: Yep, same behaviour

Comment: Can you share the data in the question?

Comment: I added printscreens to the post

Comment: Instead of sharing output, share the code where you are sorting and logging

Comment: Your sort isn't returning `0` ever so things that are even return -1 as if the `a` was less than the `b`. Use `a.year - b.year`.

Comment: Sorry, it's my first post xD , I've added the actual code

Comment: Even if I return a - b, still same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I've done it to myself. I didn't realize that .sort() is mutating the original array and I was calling it for a different purpose later on in the code.

Thank you all for replying !

Answer (score 0):

As you're doing it in the browser console - don't forget to refresh the page before each run.

Because if you don't - `const outputThree...` this will throw an error.

For me - `Nicolaus Copernicus` goes first in all examples with `1473`.

I tried with smaller data set and it seems to work correctly. Galileo goes first everywhere.

```
const inventors = [
  { first: 'Albert', year: 2 },
  { first: 'Isaac', year: 3 },
  { first: 'Galileo', year: 1 },
];

const outputThree = inventors.sort((a , b) => a.year - b.year )
console.table(outputThree) // Galileo first
console.log(outputThree) // Galileo first
console.log(outputThree[0]) // Galileo first
```